# Visual Studio Cannot Publish Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl, visual-studio-2015

My ASP.NET web project is going to call the cURL using `WebRequest` 
I used to call PayPal's cURL to get the access token, hence I used the code below:

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`

I can build the project and run in debug mode. However, when I click Publish, Visual Studio returns the following error.

> 'System.Net.SecurityProtocolType' does not contain a definition for 'Tls11'

I tried to use Visual Studio 2015 & 2017 to publish the web, but still not works.

[image: Able to run in debug mode]

For the background information: My project is running .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with .NET framework 4.5 and has an open bug. The issue is that the compiler does not include the `int` enumeration for `Tls11`.

Use this as a workaround:

```
const int SecurityProtocolTypeSsl3  = 48;
const int SecurityProtocolTypeTls11 = 768;
const int SecurityProtocolTypeTls12 = 3072;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= (SecurityProtocolType)(SecurityProtocolTypeTls12 | SecurityProtocolTypeTls11 | SecurityProtocolTypeSsl3);
```

Comment: @NewHand Happy to help.